# Netffos X9 always starts each app / activity as new

Tags: applications

I have TP-Link's Netffos X9 and from the very beginning I noticed a weird thing. Each application or activity is always started as brand new. Always, no matter, if I saw or was using given app just like 5 minutes ago, I see loader screen and a home / startup screen, instead of the one, which I left off.

I've been using around a dozen different mobile devices with Android 8.1 and hundreds other with other (older) versions of Android and this is the first time I see such a weird situation.

I have enabled Developers Options and tripple-checked that option *Don't keep activities* / *Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it* is **disabled**. I have also checked that a few applications in topic are listed among *Developers options > Inactive apps* as **active**. And yet, each time I start it up, they seems to be starting up as freshly new, showing welcome / home / startup screen.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how to prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Netffos X9 (and probably all other TP-LINK's phones) comes with a handy battery optimization functionality which actually kills all the applications that are in background 3 minutes after phone's screen turns off.

One need to go to: `⚙ > Battery > Off-screen cleanup` and disable this feature for all applications that should stay in background (and eventually be turned off by system default process, i.e. after few hours).

All applications in question were listed and enabled on the above mentioned list. Turning off this feature for all those applications resolved the issue.